# STM32 Timer Output compare not working proper

Tags: timer, embedded, stm32, nucleo

I am using STM32L476 Nucleo board and STM32CubeMX. I want to use Output Compare channel 1 for timeout of 2 ms. I have configured the timer, but the timer is not giving interrupts for Output Compare. I am getting interrupts for the period I gave to the timer, but not for output compare.

Here is my timer configuration:

```
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_SlaveConfigTypeDef sSlaveConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
  TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 1 */
  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = TIMER1_PRESCALER_VAL;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = TIMER_PERIOD;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim1, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sSlaveConfig.SlaveMode = TIM_SLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  sSlaveConfig.InputTrigger = TIM_TS_ITR0;
  if (HAL_TIM_SlaveConfigSynchro(&htim1, &sSlaveConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_OC1REF;
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger2 = TIM_TRGO2_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_ACTIVE;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 1000 * TIMER_OC_1_VAL;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
  sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
  if (HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakFilter = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2State = TIM_BREAK2_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2Polarity = TIM_BREAK2POLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2Filter = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim1, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htim1,TIM_IT_CC1);

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim1);

}
```

I tried changing the `sConfigOC.Pulse` value but I don't see the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Do you check for the right interrupt flag in the interrupt handler?
Also keep in mind that you have to clear the flag right away.

My IRQHandler looks like this, if this is any help for you.

```
void TIM3_IRQHandler(void) {

    if(LL_TIM_IsActiveFlag_CC1(TIM3) == 1) {
        LL_TIM_ClearFlag_CC1(TIM3);
        TimerCaptureCompare_Callback();
    }
}
```

---

Edit:

OK as it seems, the `HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback` interrupt is only fired when the timer overflows (i. e., resets).
**This means that you have to enable the overflow interrupt**, as the `HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT` only enables the capture/compare interrupt. 
You only need to enable it before enabling the timer.

```
__HAL_TIM_ENABLE_IT(&tim3, TIM_IT_UPDATE );
```

Comment: This flag is cleared in the timer handler function which is part of HAL library.

Comment: Ok, I did some research and found some interesting stuff. But it isn't well documented.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace "TIM_IT_CC1" with "TIM_CHANNEL_1".

Comment: Although it might fix the problem, this is more of a comment than an answer as it is a question and without context.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to initialize the output pin before starting the timer like that:

```
/* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */
HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim1);

/* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */
HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htim1,TIM_IT_CC1);
```

Second, you have to start the Output timer

```
HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT( &htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1 );
HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT( &htim1 );
```

Yyour output pin are enable like that:
(this code is for Stm32F4xx)

```
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9; // channel 1
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_TIM1;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

I am not sure you need the BREAK code. Have a look 17.3.12 Using the break function in the Reference Manual